# two dictionaries to make a new one, difficult referencing

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, reference

This is what my code looks like thus far:

Given dictionaries, d1 and d2, create a new dictionary with the following property: for each entry (a, b) in d1, if there is an entry (b, c) in d2, then the entry (a, c) should be added to the new dictionary.
 For example, if d1 is {2:3, 8:19, 6:4, 5:12} and d2 is {2:5, 4:3, 3:9}, then the new dictionary should be {2:9, 6:3}
 Associate the new dictionary with the variable  d3

```
d3 ={} 
for i in d1:
    for i in d2:
        if d1.get(i,default=none) in d2:
            d3[d1] = d2.get(i,default = None)
```

Comment: Some pointers: are you sure you need to loop through `d2`? If you've already checked if the value in `d1` is in `d2`, why do you need to use `get` with a fallback value? You have two loops with the same loop variable.

Comment: Some things:
1) You can't use the same variable name in the for loops. The "i" from the first for loop is lost in the inner code.  2) The inner for loop is unnecessary since you are checking if the value from d1 is a key in d2.  3) d3[d1] is not what you want.  4) get() already has None as the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Python can express this beautifully. Too bad it's homework and you probably can't use dict comprehensions or whatever other limitations your "teacher" gives you

```
>>> d1 = {2:3, 8:19, 6:4, 5:12}
>>> d2 = {2:5, 4:3, 3:9}
>>> d3 = {a:d2[b] for a, b in d1.items() if b in d2}
>>> d3
{2: 9, 6: 3}
```

For Python2.5 or Python2.6 use a generator expression with `dict()`

```
d3 = dict((a, d2[b]) for a, b in d1.items() if b in d2)
```

For 2.4 see @KP's answer

Comment: @KP. I don't believe all the extra clutter and inefficiency for a 2.4+ answer is necessary for a homework question. If anyone is teaching Python <2.7 they should be shot.

Comment: `d1.items()` or `d1.iteritems()`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, the best choice depends if you are using Python2 or Python3. `.items()` works on both and is not too terrible if `d` isn't huge

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you like one-liners:

```
d3 = dict([(k, d2[v]) for k, v in d1.items() if v in d2])
```